# PostGIS Multi-Ring Buffers Around Lines

Tags: postgis, buffer

I would like to create a multi-ring buffer around a stream network and add a default floating value to each each buffer ring.  I currently have the following SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE public.stream_buffer
AS
SELECT s.id AS id_streams, ST_Difference(
    ST_Union(ST_Buffer(ST_transform(geom, 3005),50)),
    ST_Union(ST_Buffer(ST_transform(geom, 3005),0))
    )
AS geom
FROM public.streams s
GROUP BY s.id

UNION ALL
SELECT s.id AS id_streams, ST_Difference(
    ST_Union(ST_Buffer(ST_transform(geom, 3005),100)),
    ST_Union(ST_Buffer(ST_transform(geom, 3005),50))
    )
AS geom
FROM public.streams s
GROUP BY s.id

UNION ALL

SELECT s.id AS id_streams, ST_Difference(
    ST_Union(ST_Buffer(ST_transform(geom, 3005),200)),
    ST_Union(ST_Buffer(ST_transform(geom, 3005),100))
    )
AS geom
FROM public.streams s
GROUP BY s.id

UNION ALL

SELECT s.id AS id_streams, ST_Difference(
    ST_Union(ST_Buffer(ST_transform(geom, 3005),300)),
    ST_Union(ST_Buffer(ST_transform(geom, 3005),200))
    )
AS geom
FROM public.streams s
GROUP BY s.id;
```

Resulting in the following mess of un-dissolved and valued buffers:
[image: example]

I have tried the following for a single buffer distance, but don't know how to connect various buffer distances, substract the difference and place a value in each buffered ring around stream.

```
CREATE TABLE stream_buffer_100 AS
SELECT 
   g.path[1] as id, 
    g.geom::geometry(Polygon, 3005) as geom 
 FROM
    (SELECT 
      (ST_Dump(ST_UNION(ST_Buffer(st_transform(geom,3005), 100)))).* 
    FROM public.streams
 ) as g;

ALTER TABLE  public.stream_buffer_100                                                                 
ADD COLUMN vul float8;                      
UPDATE stream_buffer_100 set vul = 0.75;
```

Below is what I would like with a floating point value for each buffer ring:
[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Are you trying to clip the buffers so none of them overlap?

Comment: @jbalk your sql query below causes the same result as my original sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one method to make ring buffers.  I create the first buffer, then use it to make the second buffer by taking the difference of the buffer around the first buffer and the geometry of the first buffer (subtract the first buffer from the new buffer to create the hole), then repeat for each ring:

```
with buffer1 as
  (select 0::numeric buffer_from, 50::numeric buffer_to, 
      st_buffer(st_transform(st_union(geom),3005),50) geom 
  from public.streams),
buffer2 as
  (select 50::numeric buffer_from, 100::numeric buffer_to, 
      st_difference(st_buffer(st_transform(st_union(geom),3005),100),st_buffer(st_transform(st_union(geom),3005),50)) geom 
  from public.streams),
buffer3 as 
  (select 100::numeric buffer_from, 200::numeric buffer_to, 
      st_difference(st_buffer(st_transform(st_union(geom),3005),200),
      st_buffer(st_transform(st_union(geom),3005),100)) geom 
  from public.streams),
buffer4 as
  (select 200::numeric buffer_from, 300::numeric buffer_to, 
      st_difference(st_buffer(st_transform(st_union(geom),3005),300),
      st_buffer(st_transform(st_union(geom),3005),200)) geom 
  from public.streams)
select * from buffer1
union
select * from buffer2
union
select * from buffer3
union
select * from buffer4;
```

This gives ring buffers:

[image: all buffers]
[image: buffer 2 and buffer 4]
[image: buffers dissolved on distance]

Comment: This doesn't result in the desired dissolution of the buffered rings when multiple line segments are used.

Comment: I didn't understand the terminology you're using.  I got it after looking at your picture again.  Anyway, you just need to group by buffer distance.  See my edits.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't result in a dissolved buffer around the streams.  It looks like it is taking the difference of the undissolved buffers around each line segment, similar to my original result illustrated in question.

Comment: Oops.  I had the grouping in the wrong place.  Edited again.

Comment: You can't assign only 1 stream id to each buffer because you're dissolving the buffers on buffer distance, not stream id.  You could aggregate a list of all the stream ids associated with each buffer.  It's not a 1:1 relationship.  There will be many stream ids for each buffer, excepting buffers for isolated streams outside of twice the buffer distance of any other stream, which would get one id.

Comment: In your second screenshot, the buffers would have 14 associated stream ids.  One buffer for each id (14 in total), dissolved into one buffer.